# View returns "0" when running IIS Express

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller

I am trying to display data from an SSMS table within a table on my html page, but when I run my program via IIS, it returns "0" on the page but does not crash. I am attempting to display the data via ADO.NET Entity Data Model to display LoyaltyID column from table tLoyalty. I would like the page to display the table with the LoyaltyID in each table row. Any help is much appreciated.

HTML table within view:

```
<div>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Loyalty ID</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            
            @foreach (var query in Model)
            {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @query.tLoyalty
                </td>
            </tr>                     
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Model class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class tLoyalty
{
    public int LoyaltyID { get; set; }
    public string LoyaltyNumber { get; set; }
    public int StoreID { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DateOfIssue { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> LoyaltyStatusID { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
using Web3.Controllers;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography.Xml;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Web3.Models;

namespace Web3.Controllers
{
    public class LoyaltyController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
        return View();
        }

        public ActionResult LoyaltyInfo()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult LoyaltyQuery()
        {
            var context = new tLoyalty();
            var query = context.LoyaltyID.ToString();
            return Content(query);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is 0? status code? body content? what is in the inspector or html debugger?

Comment: When I run IIS, the page loads but does not populate any html - it only produces the "0" character on the web page in the top left corner.  In the debugger "context.LoyaltyID" stores int 0

Comment: but did you see the html?

Comment: what is the value of "query" when you pass it to the Content?

Comment: No, when I run IIS there is no html displayed, it is just a blank page with "0" at the top left.  When stepping through the debugger in the controller, the value of "query" is NULL at the "var query = context.LoyaltyID.ToString();" line , and "0" of type string when passed into the content.

Comment: you should resolve first why are you passing a null object to the view

Comment: Okay, thanks.  To answer your question, no I do not see any html whatsoever.  Just a blank page with "0".  The value of "context" and "query" remains NULL until it gets to the line where it is passed into Content, in which it then becomes 0 type string.  I will have to look into this issue.

Comment: For sure something is coming wrong there and then you dont have the expected output, always resolve from inside to outside